# Select certain files in a directory to copy

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Im trying to copy 5 files from one directory to another, but I only get the first file in the list and no more. Why? What did I do wrong that I am not getting all 5 files?

```
    # list of files from source directory that I want to copy to destination folder
    $file_list = "240","240.old","errors","errstation.log","wagdlg4.log"

    # Copy each file
    foreach ($file in $file_list)
    {
    Copy-Item "C:\test\$file" (New-Item -type Directory "C:\test2\" -name (Get-Date -f      MMddyyyy_hhmm)).FullName
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this bit:

```
(New-Item -type Directory "C:\test2\" -name (Get-Date -f MMddyyyy_hhmm)).FullName
```

Is attempting to create a new directory for every file you copy.  However the directory name is the same most likely because your timestamp in the name only goes to minute resolution.  When it tries to create that same directory again (on the second file) you will get an error.

I would go this route:

```
$file_list = "240","240.old","errors","errstation.log","wagdlg4.log"
$dir = New-Item -type Directory "C:\test2\" -name (Get-Date -f MMddyyyy_hhmm)
$file_list | Foreach { Copy-Item "C:\test\$_" $dir.Fullname}
```

Comment: What would be the best way to rearrange it so I get all the files in the newly created folder?

Comment: I had tried to create the directory first and wound up with the directory and all the files at the same level. :-)
    <code>(New-Item -type Directory "C:\test2\" -name (Get-Date -f   MMddyyyy_hhmm)).FullName
$file_list = "240","240.old","errors","errstation.log","wagdlg4.log"

foreach ($file in $file_list)
{
  Copy-Item "C:\test\$file" -Destination "C:\test2\" 
}</code>

Comment: Your original code would copy into the same directory as well.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: just to get those files into their own directory with a timestamp on the directory because I was going to schedule a job. Thanks Again. :-)